# Erratic errors in libfreenect on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, usb, opencv, driver, computer-vision

I'm running a 3D SLAM application ([RTAB-Map](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap)) on my Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie. The sensor I'm using is a Kinect v1 (Xbox 360) camera connected to one of the USB ports.

I've installed [libfreenect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) from source, following [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/hntuan94/home/kinect/-2-connect-kinect-to-raspberry-pi-2-using-libfreenect). After the tutorial, I was able to run the sample tests normally, but after I've installed [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) from source, the problem started. Most times (~90%) I try to start the mapping process on RTAB-Map (or when I try one of the demos from libfreenect) I get one of the following errors:

```
send_cmd: Output control transfer failed (-1)
freenect_fetch_reg_pad_info: send_cmd read -1 bytes (expected 8)
freenect_camera_init(): Failed to fetch registration pad info for device
```

or

```
send_cmd: Input control transfer failed (18)
freenect_fetch_reg_pad_info: send_cmd read 18 bytes (expected 118)
```

Every now and then, libfreenect actually starts working and I manage to run the application.

What is causing this behavior? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance. I'll provide any additional details necessary.

**UPDATE**

Here's part of the output from `dmesg`:

```
[ 2137.035095] usb 1-1.5.3: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 2140.086494] usb 1-1.5.3: new high-speed USB device number 14 using dwc_otg
[ 2140.189807] usb 1-1.5.3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02ae
[ 2140.189831] usb 1-1.5.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[ 2140.189845] usb 1-1.5.3: Product: Xbox NUI Camera
[ 2140.189857] usb 1-1.5.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[ 2140.189869] usb 1-1.5.3: SerialNumber: A00366814383041A
[ 2140.190947] gspca_main: kinect-2.14.0 probing 045e:02ae
[ 2972.032617] gspca_main: kinect-2.14.0 probing 045e:02ae
[ 2972.036198] gspca_main: kinect-2.14.0 probing 045e:02ae
[ 2972.218569] usb 1-1.5.3: USB disconnect, device number 14
[ 2975.012840] usb 1-1.5.3: new high-speed USB device number 15 using dwc_otg
[ 2975.116115] usb 1-1.5.3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02ae
[ 2975.116138] usb 1-1.5.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[ 2975.116152] usb 1-1.5.3: Product: Xbox NUI Camera
[ 2975.116165] usb 1-1.5.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[ 2975.116177] usb 1-1.5.3: SerialNumber: A00366814383041A
[ 2975.117261] gspca_main: kinect-2.14.0 probing 045e:02ae
```

Things I've tried:

- Reserving memory: `vm.min_free_kbytes = 32768` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`
- Copying `udev` rules: `sudo cp /libfreenect/platform/linux/udev/51-kinect.rules /etc/udev/rules.d`
- `ln -s /home/[my username]/.Xauthority /root/.Xauthority`
- Blacklisting `gspca_kinect` driver: `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf > blacklist gspca_kinect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved in the following commit: [raspberry pi3 fix](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/commit/88166014859c09f6ad6a93f0862bdcc4e46dc87e).

So, apparently, it was a timing issue. Now the sensor starts normally every time.